# GraphQL question about good patterns in query design

Tags: api, graphql

I'm pretty new in Graphql and API development in general.

There are many tutorials around but sometimes I have doubts about some implementation patterns.
In particular, I was wondering about best practices for writing GraphQL schemas.

In almost all tutorials (as is the case with REST APIs) when it comes to writing a query to retrieve a list of entities it is usually presented as follows:

```
query{
    Books{
       id,
       title,
       something
}}
```

Almost always another query is then presented for the recovery of a single object of that entity, for example:

```
query{
    Book(id:id){
       id,
       title,
       something
}}
```

here comes my first implementation doubt.
When I go to write the function that interfaces with the database for data retrieval, the code is practically the same for both resolvers.
Only that in the second case I will add a where clause (e.g. where `bookID = id`)

At this point I was wondering, why can't I use a single query and add the various filters as arguments?

```
query{
    Books(filters:{id:id, title:title, ...}){
       id,
       title,
       something
}}
```

What's the point of adding a different query for each filter?

- Books
- BookById
- BookbyTitle
- ...

Is it just a matter of better organization of the entry points or am I missing something else?

While for REST API this makes sense to me, with GraphQL I fail to see the benefit since the overfetching is not a problem.

Could someone be so kind as to enlighten me?

Comment: the only answer I could give myself is related to some method to limit the end user whit his query. For example add the ability to query for huge relational fields (1 to N) only to the endpoint BookbyId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that this is a subjective decision and you could go either way. You should expect opinionated answers here.

When you define a query in your typeDefs, you also specify what you expect to get back. Ex:

```
query {
  getBook (id: ID!): Book
  getBooks: [Book!]!
}
```

In the first query you know that the return object is a single book. In the second you're going to get an array of books.

If you build queries that can either return one or more books that's fine - you can expect an array which may only have one book in it.

It's when you expect a single book but get multiple books back that you may face problems in your front end. If you query books by ID you expect a single book but if you query books by title you might get 0, 1, or N books back if there happen to be multiple books with the same title (e.g. paperback vs hardback editions of the same title).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your feedback. I'm curious about "opinionated answers" at this point. Either way the return type is already a good reason to split the queries. in this case it would be useful for documentation purposes since developers would be aware of what kind of return they can get.

for internal use instead I think that even the first approach (through filters) could be fine for me, since I know well what data is unique and what to expect in the response.

Comment: If you are designing both the server and the client you are in the driver's seat and can do what you want. The challenge will be when more developers start using your server. Will the documentation be adequate? Will they make easily avoidable mistakes? Also consider the complexity of your queries. If someone specifies both `id` and `title` which one takes precedence? `id` implies a single result, `title` implies many and the `id` and `title` may not match. Now extend that to more query variables. Which combinations are valid? How do expectations change based on the combination of variables?

Comment: all are right observations and already the first answer was a good reason to consider split queries. however in my case the filters are meant to be concatenated with logical ANDs. so im not concerned about precedence.

Comment: i agree that the challenge start whit external consumers